# ASP.NET MVC failed to deploy on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, cloud

I'm trying to upload an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application to Windows Azure. The upload ok but the configuration (automatic operation just after upload) failed.

Any idea ? (I'm new in Windows Azure)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there in the second screen shot.

When you upload your package from the portal the dialog has a checkbox at the bottom that says "Deploy even if one or more roles contain a single instance" That needs to be checked if you are choosing to deploy to a single instance.

This is required since the SLA cannot be maintained with a single instance. There are times when the single instance needs to have OS updates applied or sometimes there are hardware failures. Having more than one instance is the only way to continue serving requests when one of these events occur.

You probably will not want to deploy a production solution with a single instance. But, for the dev cycle you can certainly get by with 1.

Comment: Yes I know. But it's not an obligation to have 2 instances ? How create this second instance ?

Comment: There are a couple ways to do this. Inside of Visual Studio under the cloud project, there will be a roles folder. Double click on the role that represents your web role for the mvc project. There is an entry for number of instances there. This is merely an editor that updates a set of xml files. You can also update the cscfg file directly and change <Instances count="N" />

Comment: You are right in that it is not an obligation. The warning is there so you know that the SLA cannot be met. You can choose to override the warning with the checkbox.

Comment: One more question. I linked my Windows Azure website to a Ressource ("SQL Database"). How can I set the connection string of my web site to the connection string of SQL Server ?

Comment: There are a couple of options here too. You can put the connection string as a "string" property in Azure configuration. Then you can read it with RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue or the new CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting. Another option is to put the connection string in web.config just like you have always done. The disadvantage of the web.config is that if you need to update you have to visit every instance. Azure configuration can be changed from the portal in one location. All instances are updated when the Azure configuration settings are changed in the portal

Comment: I will have more question when I'll be at home :)

Comment: Feel free to post more questions on SO. I think the original question has been answered for future SO users. More SO questions will raise visibility of the questions for more people to answer and more to see answers in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the new portal you have to explicitly check a check box to allow deployment with less that two instances:

[image]

There is absolutely no obligation to use 2 instances. There is only SLA that comes into place only if you have 2 or more instances. I have production roles with 1 instance and I am very happy to use the Windows Azure services.

**UPDATE**

Just ntoed the "Linked Resources" comment on the first answer. So here are my 2 cents on it too: Linked resources feature is just a way for us developers to have a quick overview of our application and to quickly navigate between the components. There is nothing to do with our application's configuration files. You can set your Windows Azure SQL Database connection string as you normaly do with regular apps - in web.config (web.release.config)